# SFML 2.1 getchar equivalent

Tags: c++, sfml

Is there an equivalent in SFML for getchar()? I've tried getchar() and getch() but they only work on the console window, not the graphics one.

Answer (score 1):

Check out how [events](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/window-events.php) work in SFML. Especially the [TextEntered](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/window-events.php#the-textentered-event).

Answer (score -1):

To answer you're question "Is there a getchar(); , no not really.
SFML is event driven so you really need to check keyboard events for the window.

You can create a function to send in keys and make a switch.
A game book I have "SFML Game Development" uses code like this.
You can also check other things like if shift is being pressed, and what to do if that is the case.

```
std::string toString(sf::Keyboard::Key key)
{
#define KEYTOSTRING_CASE(KEY) case sf::Keyboard::KEY: return #KEY;

switch(key)

{
KEYTOSTRING_CASE(Unknown)
KEYTOSTRING_CASE(A)
KEYTOSTRING_CASE(B)
KEYTOSTRING_CASE(C)
KEYTOSTRING_CASE(ect...)

}
return"";

}
```

Comment: One should not deduce the character from a key press/down/up input, that's why there's the TextEntered event and using macros isn't really a solution either.